# Can not Download 'digest' package in R

Tags: r, plot, package, box, digest

I am trying to create clustered box plots in R. Everything about my code seems on track, but when I try to run it I get the error warning

> "Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘digest’.

When I try to download the package `digest` in the R package Installer I get a bunch of errors stating that the download of `digest` failed.

How do I get the `digest` package, OR is there a way to do clustered box plots without this? Thanks!

Comment: Check if R version is up to date?

Comment: It is a macOS specific problem for which we got issue tickets #76, #77, #78 and #79 at GitHub.  I escalated it to the r-devel list and CRAN yesterdas, no answer yet AFAIK.  I just replied on-list to bump this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar error message recently and managed to solve the problem by downloading the tar.gz file directly from the CRAN Repository (see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/digest/index.html and download "digest_0.6.15.tar.gz") and then you can install it in RStudio (Tools -> Install Packages -> Install from Package/Archive File).

Comment: Same thing from the R prompt:  `install.packages("digest", type="source")` (if you have a repo set, else it prompts).

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with `install.packages("digest")` on OS10.11.6 (running with the defaults). But it worked by specifying the repos:

```
install.packages('digest', repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')
```